# Caliburn re-run filter

Tags: silverlight, caliburn

In caliburn, i have view with button. Button action is filtered by action filter. On view is textbox. When i change textbox content, i want to rerun action filter, how to perform that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found Dependencies attribute :)

Comment: Just for reference: http://caliburn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/55301#1240191